# about:preferences#security in Firefox blank

Tags: firefox

The settings in Firefox have that Security tab but it shows a blank page only.

about:preferences#security

Do I need to use a "trick" to open those settings now?

Version 48.0.1 "Firefox is up to date"

Comment: Current version of Firefox is 48.0.2, but I can't repro this and I don't recall it happening in 48.0.1.

Comment: Have you tried starting with all add-ons/extensions disabled? With a new profile?

Comment: I have version 50.0a2, developer's edition, and have no problem.